# Has anyone tried using ZooKeeper?

Tags: caching, memcached, apache-zookeeper

I was currently looking into memcached as way to coordinate a group of server, but came across [Apache's ZooKeeper](http://hadoop.apache.org/zookeeper/) along the way. It looks interesting, and Yahoo uses it, so it shouldn't be bad, but I'd never heard of it before, so I'm kind of skeptical. Has anyone else given it a try? Any comments or ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ZooKeeper and Memcached have different purposes. You can use memcached to do server coordination, but you'll have to do most of this work yourself. Memcached only allows coordination in that it caches common data lookups to be used by multiple clients. From reading ZooKeeper's documentation, it has a much broader focus than this. ZooKeeper seems to provide support for server clustering, which isn't the same as the cache clustering memcached provides.

Have a look at Brad Fitzpatrick's Linux Journal [article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7559) on memcached to get a better idea what I mean.

Answer (score 5):

To get an overview of what Zookeper is capable of, watch the following presentation by it's creators. It's capable of so much more (creating queue's, electing master processes amongst a group of peers, distributed high performance run time configurations, rendezvous points for dis-joined processes, determining if processes are still running, etc).

http://zookeeper.sourceforge.net/index.sf.shtml

To answer your question, if "coordination" is what you are looking for Zookeeper is much better targeted at that than memcached.

Answer (score 1):

Zookeeper is great for coordinating data across servers. It does a good job of ordering every transaction and making guarantees that transactions happen in order. However when first breaking into it the documentation sucks; it's very 'high-level' without enough concrete examples or explanations as how to properly handle certain events. One of the included examples (as of version 3.3.3) had its own bugs in it.

Your code will also need to be cognizant of event driven interactions, and polling interactions. With massively distributed architecture, when acting upon 'events' you can inadvertently create a stampede that could not be desirable for your environment (herding effect).